# What To Do With Crash Log?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash-reports

I had some crash logs sent by the user but don't know what to do with them now.

I tried opening them in xcode 4 but can't understand anything, its mostly just numbers.

Here is a similar crash log from my own device that was symbolized.  It seems to be the same crash though.  Can anyone tell me whats happening?

Notice how its not symbolizing the lines for my actual app (Curl).
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100306/how-to-understand-crash-log-of-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932210/viewing-ad-hoc-crash-reports-from-an-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/).  Notably :

```
$ sudo cp /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/Resources/symbolicatecrash /usr/local/bin/
$ symbolicatecrash report.crash MobileLines.app.dSYM > report-with-symbols.crash

    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib           0x300c87ec objc_msgSend + 20
    1   MobileLines               0x00006434 -[BoardView setSelectedPiece:] (BoardView.m:321)
    2   MobileLines               0x000064c2 -[BoardView touchesBegan:withEvent:] (BoardView.m:349)
    3   UIKit                     0x30a740ac -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 264
    4   UIKit                     0x30a66110 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 248
    5   UIKit                     0x30a6565c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 4088
    6   GraphicsServices          0x3169b0b4 PurpleEventCallback + 428
    7   GraphicsServices          0x3169d818 HeartbeatVBLCallback + 152
    8   IOMobileFramebuffer       0x31f3e8f8 IOMobileFramebufferNotifyFunc + 124
    9   com.apple.framework.IOKit 0x30f342b8 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 304
    10  CoreFoundation            0x3025ced4 __CFMachPortPerform + 72
    11  CoreFoundation            0x3025bed6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 2364
    12  CoreFoundation            0x3025b584 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
    13  GraphicsServices          0x316998e4 GSEventRunModal + 268
    14  UIKit                     0x30a5e308 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
    15  UIKit                     0x30a671dc UIApplicationMain + 1064
    16  MobileLines               0x00002090 main (main.m:16)
    17  MobileLines               0x0000202c start + 44
```